# log4j2 - print null/empty string when system/environment property is null/not present

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have following pattern in my `log4j2.xml` config file and it is printing the `FILE_NAME` variable as expected when it is present:

```
<Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
   %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- $${sys:FILE_NAME} [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
</Property>
```

However, in certain situation, the FILE_NAME property is null/not present, in those cases it is printing the value as `${sys:FILE_NAME}`.
How can I avoid printing this or at least print a `null` or `empty` value?